Domain inaccessible
One of my domains went offline today. The domain is used for email, no other services, and  emails are no longer being received.
The domain is associated with a GMail account. The domain registration is through register.com and is good for two additional years.
To diagnose further, I tried
dig <domain> MX

and I'm told connection timed out; no servers could be reached. I checked my own email domain, which has a similar setup, and, as expected, I get a response with 5 different Google mail exchange servers. So, clearly something is not right.
Next, I perform a WHOIS search on the domain in question, which shows me the name servers for that domain:
ns1.clustermax.net  208.81.180.115
ns2.clustermax.net  209.212.253.188
ns3.clustermax.net  70.36.32.73

An nslookup of any of the servers fails, and I can't ping any of the servers by their numeric IP address either.
My conclusion is that these servers have ceased operation recently. I have no idea who that clustermax.net organization is.
The domain had at some time a hosted web site associated with it, but that hasn't been used in a long time, so I haven't paid for hosting in years. Hosting was originally with a small local provider in San Diego that got acquired by another company, which got acquired by another company. I assume that during one of these acquisitions the domain ended up on the clustermax.net name servers.
Two questions:

Am I diagnosing this scenario correctly, and my name servers have indeed gone offline?
How do I fix this and restore email service? (I have an AWS account that presumably gives me access to AWS's name servers, so I assume I could move the domain there)


Why don't you tell us what the domain name is so we can give you accurate, targeted answers?

@joeqwerty it's eclipsemail.org

Clustermax.net is offline... there are no dns records for it: https://www.nslookup.io/domains/clustermax.net/dns-records/#cloudflare
You've got it right though... You have to go to where you registered the domain and use some other name servers. It looks like you used register.com

The eclipsemail.org domain is currently hijacked.You may want to contact the owners at: https://www.eclipse.org/

@GregAskew can you clarify what you mean by "currently hijacked"? I own the eclipsemail.org domain and have owned it for almost twenty years. The original meaning was indeed related to an email client that I wrote for the Eclipse platform (as in eclipse.org) about two decades ago, but the Eclipse Foundation has never owned that domain.

Yes, those name servers are down. The company hosting those name servers may have ceased operations or may have experienced some type of critical outage. The domain name is registered with Register.com. If you have an account login at Register.com you can log in and move the name servers somewhere else. You'll have to create the needed DNS records from scratch.
If you don't have an account at Register.com you'll need to contact them to find out how to proceed from here.
To find out what the DNS records are/were, you can sign up for a free account at SecurityTrails (https://securitytrails.com), do a lookup up of the domain name, and look at the historical data. This will show you what the DNS recrods were so that you can recreate them accurately.

Thanks especially for the tip about SecurityTrails, which allowed me to restore the original MX server names. I was able to switch back to register.com's own name servers without problems. I wasn't able to see the original MX server priorities in SecurityTrails, but I used a similar set of priorities that my other account uses, and that seemed to have worked

Glad to help...

remember that you need to accept this answer due else we will be reminded until the end of the universe to solve this problem ;)
